# Javascript doesn't wait for STRIPE.COM function to finish before executing next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

stripe.com is a payment processing site like paypal.com. in two steps they actually execute a credit card. first step to validate the card information and in second pass it deduct amount and credit to merchant account.
however, for me the situation is i need to verify credit card information using stripe.com. so what i did is, call a function "stripeResponseHandler" which pass CC info to stripe and get response within few seconds. it works great. But the problem is, javascript/jquery doesn't wait until that function execution finished. Fact is, i have set a variable to determine the immediate next step based on stripeResponseHandler response.
is there are any way by which  i can stop further execution until stripeResponseHandler function finished? Here is few lines of code:

```
var cc_validate=1;
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {  //alert('stripeResponseHandler called');
    if (response.error) {
        cc_validate=1;
    } else {  //CC info Correct. Now Charge using PHP by Submit this form
        cc_validate=0;
        alert('CC Validation passed in stripeResponseHandler call.');
    }
}
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
    Stripe.createToken({
        number: '4242424242424242',
        cvc: '123',
        exp_month: '11',
        exp_year: '2015'
    }, stripeResponseHandler);

  alert(cc_validate); // it always output 1(but i need 0 for valid CC)
  //'execution always comes here before complete stripeResponseHandler function execution'
```

Comment: javascript is async with ajax calls. do your work in the responsehandler.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: so you mean, shall i write my code inside response.error else block? i know it should work but the problem is i have many more logics afterward where i need cc_validate value. so i need to stop execution until stripeResponseHandler function finished execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createToken is doing the validation asynchronously as most functions that make network calls do.
Move your processing into stripeResponseHandler.

## Update

It is not possible to stop and wait for a network call complete then start processing again without using callbacks. Move your furthering processing into a function and call that function from function stripeResponseHandler.

Comment: is it impossible to wait execution until stripeResponseHandler function execution is completed?

Comment: Unless there's an option like `async: false` in the Stripe API, yes.

Comment: @user2988325 If there was a way to wait until the function returned, the tab, if not the entire browser, would be locked up and frozen.  That is why async calls exist.